# IIS Express option unavailable in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express

[image: rightclicking on website project]

How do I enable the option to use IIS Express for a website project in my solution?

I have installed IIS Express but it does not show up as an option? I would like to use this because at the moment I cannot use IIS on my machine.

Comment: Why on earth are you using a Web Site project?

Comment: I tried converting to a web application project but returns too many errors. what is the best way to convert this, preferably quickly?

Comment: We can't use Web Application projects because they require all the code to be in one language :\

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Visual Studio 2010 SP1 installed?  SP1 is required to get the IIS Express option in the Web tab of your project properties.  (don't forget to also do a windows update)  Also, you should install the Visual Studio 2010 Web Standards Update as well.

Comment: How does the Web Standards Update affect IIS Express? Not criticising, just seems unrelated.

Comment: @GregB - it is unrelated, that's why I said "should".  If you're upgrading to SP1, you should also install the WSU

Comment: Is that a question or a statement?

Comment: @Gromer sorry that is an ozzie thing, it is a statement

Comment: @user603007 - are you certain?  If you go to Help->About what version number does it say it is?  If you have SP1 installed, there should be a menu item for it.

Comment: @MystereMan it says version number 4.0.30319 SP1Rel

Answer (score 1):

As 'Mystere Man' said you need VS 2010 service pack (SP1) to see IIS Express option in VS. If you are sure that you have SP1 installed, did you check if IIS Express exists in the installation folder? (%programfiles%\IIS Express or %programfiles(x86)\IIS Express)

If it is not installed, you can install it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I opened the site through IIS. The only way to see that the project was opened through IIS is the lack of this button and the title of the Web Site project looks like: `http://localhost/x` rather than `http://localhost:1111`.

To get the ability to use IIS Express, you have to remove the Web Site project from the solution and use Add Existing Web Site then choose the file system.